# NEON simple vector assignment intrinsic?

Tags: c, arm, simd, neon, intrinsics

Having `r1`,`r3` and `r4` of type `uint32x4_t` loaded into NEON registers I have the following code:

```
r3 = veorq_u32(r0,r3);   
r4 = r1;    
r1 = vandq_u32(r1,r3);   
r4 = veorq_u32(r4,r2);   
r1 = veorq_u32(r1,r0);
```

And I was just wondering whether GCC actually translates `r4 = r1` into the `vmov` instruction. Looking at the disassembled code I wasn't surprised that it didn't. (moreover I can't figure out what the generated assembly code actually does)

Skimming through ARM's NEON intrinsics reference I couldn't find any simple vector->vector assignment intrinsic.

What's the easiest way to achieve this? I'm not sure how an inlined assembly code would look like since I don't know in which registers were `r1` and `r4` assigned by `vld1q_u32`. I don't need an actual swap, just assignment.

Comment: how does the assembly look like? did you compile with -O2 ?

Comment: Yes, there's just a bunch of logical instructions but no `vmov` which I would expect.

Comment: If you think a intrinsic function for a variation of NEON instruction `vmov` is missing, feel free to post a bug at http://gcc.gnu.org/ with the opcode, argument, documentation link, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C has a concept of an abstract machine. Assignments and other operations are described in terms of this abstract machine. The assignment `r4 = r1;` says to assign r4 the value of r1 **in the abstract machine**.

When the compiler generates instructions for a program, it generally does not exactly mimic everything that occurs in the abstract machine. It translates the operations that occur in the abstract machine into processor instructions that get the same results. The compiler will skip things like move instructions if it can figure out that it can get the same results without them.

In particular, the compiler might not keep `r1` in the same place every time. It might load it from memory into some register R7 the first time you need it. But then it might implement your statement `r1 = vandq_u32(r1,r3);` by putting the result in R8 while keeping the original value of `r1` in R7. Then, when you later have `r4 = veorq_u32(r4,r2);`, the compiler can use the value in R7, because it still contains that value that `r4` would have (from the `r4 = r1;` statement) in the abstract machine.

Even if you explicitly wrote a `vmov` intrinsic, the compiler might not issue an instruction for it, as long as it issues instructions that get the same result in the end.

Comment: So are you implying the code above will work as expected nevertheless there's no `vmov` instruction in the dissassembly?

Comment: @NumberFour: Yes, you're writing in C with intrinsic functions that happen to implement the same operations that NEON instructions do.  You're not programming in asm.  It's exactly like writing scalar C with `int` variables, where you can assign them to each other and use operations like `+`, and the compiler figures out whether it needs to actually copy registers for an `=` or whether it can just read from the original register, or reload from memory.